# how to copy php files from working directory to local www folder from intellij 13

Tags: php, intellij-idea, web-deployment

I have always been using `netbeans` to develop php project but wanted to give a try to see how `intellij Ultimate (version 13 in this case)`. After installing the php plugin, and created a simple web application project, I got lost. Turns out to some hours of googling and trial and error I couldn't find that small thing that could say check to `copy the the files to remote location or remote server` etc.

I am running `fedora 19` with apache2 so my root directory is `/var/www/html/phpproject`. I am hoping to see my files from `/media/blacksensei/Repo/work/intellijworkspace/phpproject/src` copied to that folder so that I can have access to it via `http://localhost/phpproject`.

Can anyone explain this process simply for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not php developer. But what I see that it is quite simple:

1. Create Run/Debug configuration for PHP Web aplication
2. Tap `+` in `Before launch` section
3. Choose `Upload to Remote Host` and configure it

You can find more details here - http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/uploading-and-downloading-files.html#d438110e553